# Transfer file via socket , file transfered each scheduled minutes

Tags: java, android, sockets, android-asynctask

I have a project where I need to transfer a file from server (PC) to client(Android) , for example each 5 minutes. My issue is that i can send a file only for the first time , secondly it jumps over my method. I'd setup a button that onClick will fetch my file from the server. The first time I clicked it , it worked , secondly i've got an **exception**:

```
09-11 11:02:55.578: E/AndroidRuntime(13472): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-11 11:02:55.578: E/AndroidRuntime(13472): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot execute task: the task is already running.
09-11 11:02:55.578: E/AndroidRuntime(13472):    at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:538)
09-11 11:02:55.578: E/AndroidRuntime(13472):    at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:499)
09-11 11:02:55.578: E/AndroidRuntime(13472):    at com.aaandroid.MainActivity$3.onClick(MainActivity.java:63)
09-11 11:02:55.578: E/AndroidRuntime(13472):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3100)
09-11 11:02:55.578: E/AndroidRuntime(13472):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:11644)
09-11 11:02:55.578: E/AndroidRuntime(13472):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
09-11 11:02:55.578: E/AndroidRuntime(13472):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-11 11:02:55.578: E/AndroidRuntime(13472):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:126)
09-11 11:02:55.578: E/AndroidRuntime(13472):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3997)
09-11 11:02:55.578: E/AndroidRuntime(13472):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-11 11:02:55.578: E/AndroidRuntime(13472):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
09-11 11:02:55.578: E/AndroidRuntime(13472):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
09-11 11:02:55.578: E/AndroidRuntime(13472):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
09-11 11:02:55.578: E/AndroidRuntime(13472):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My Server:

```
public class TCPServer  {
  public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    // create socket
    ServerSocket servsock = new ServerSocket(64500);
    // declaring files
    while (true) {
      System.out.println("Waiting...");
      Socket sock = servsock.accept();
      System.out.println("Accepted connection : " + sock);
      // sendfile
      File myFile = new File("text.txt");

      // File
      int count;
      byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
      OutputStream out = sock.getOutputStream();
      BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(myFile));
      while ((count = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        out.write(buffer, 0, count);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
   //     sock.close();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My Client

```
class TCPClient extends AsyncTask <Void, Void, Void>{

  private final static String serverIP = "10.96.x.zzz";

  private final static int serverPort = 64500;
  private final static String inputFile = "/mnt/sdcard/Text.txt";

  /**
   * @see android.os.AsyncTask#doInBackground(Params[])
   */
  protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    int filesize = 512; // filesize temporary hardcoded
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    int bytesRead = 0;
    int current = 0;
    // localhost for testing
    try {
    Socket sock = new Socket (serverIP,serverPort);
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(inputFile);
    BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int count;
    InputStream in = sock.getInputStream();
    while((count=in.read(buffer)) >0){
        fos.write(buffer);
    }
    out.close();
    fos.flush();
    fos.close();
    sock.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      // TODO Add your own exception handling here, consider logging
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

Any ideas ? I repeat my problem is that i can't send my file on a scheduled time , it sends my file for the first time , but secondly i get exception that my task is already running.
On MainActivity 63 i'm running my doinbackground . but i use execute();
Thanks in advice !

Comment: so you should show us your mainactivity. maybe use a TimerTask and a Timer instead of AsyncTask

Comment: If i don't use AsyncTask i get networkonmainthreadexception

Comment: create your own thread-subclass instead of asynctask and start it periodically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the `AsyncTask` [javadoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html):

> The task can be executed only once (an exception will be thrown if a second execution is attempted.)

I expect that you are attempting to execute an instance of your `TCPClient` class more than once.

(This is a guess ... but you haven't included the code that runs the task in your Question.)

Comment: yeah, so is there a way that i can send not only once ?

Comment: i have an instance of my TCPClient. TCPClient tcp = new TCPClient(); tcp.execute();

Comment: You can't call `execute()` more than once on a `TCPClient` instance.  The exception is saying you are doing that.

Comment: is there another way to call execute() more than once ?

Comment: I made a quick  fix :)) instead of tcp.execute(); i did        tcpClient= (TCPClient) new TCPClient().execute();                        will this kill my device ? too many threads ?